# W7 Home Premium x64 fresh install - won't detect usb flash drive for drivers

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, installation, windows-installation

just installed W7 on a new build and can't get the drivers installed. I was having issues during the installation - it was hanging on finalizing settings - and did a new install without the ethernet connected. Installation worked, but no drivers were installed. Now it won't read a usb drive so I can't manually install the drivers. I don't have a CD/DVD drive either. At this point, I'm guessing the only thing is to try and track down a friend with a CD/DVD drive, but I'm hoping someone here might have something I can try before I do that. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

**Specifications:**

- MB: GIGABYTE GA-H110M-A (rev. 1.0) LGA 1151;
- CPU: Intel Core i5-6400 6M Skylake Quad-Core 2.7 GHz;
- GPU: GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 950 GV-N950WF2OC-2GD;
- PSU: CORSAIR CXM series CX750M 750W ATX12V v2.3;
- RAM: Crucial Ballistix Sport 4GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600

Comment: Are you plugging your thumb drive into a USB 3.0 port? Windows 7 doesn't have native support for it, so you would have to install a driver in order to get that working. If your motherboard has a USB 2.0 port, I would try plugging your thumb drive in there instead.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you can share which motherboard you are using, and while you're at it, the rest of your specs too, just in case anyone can catch a red flag with your configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the first thing I checked. USB is plugged into the 2.0 port. For added detail, when I go to the device manager, there are those yellow triangles with exclamation marks for ethernet controller, PCI Data Acquisition and Signal Processing, PCI Memory Controller, PCI Simple Communications, SM Bus Controller, and Universal Serial Bus Controller.

Comment: Sure. MB: GIGABYTE GA-H110M-A (rev. 1.0) LGA 1151; CPU: Intel Core i5-6400 6M Skylake Quad-Core 2.7 GHz; GPU: GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 950 GV-N950WF2OC-2GD; PSU: CORSAIR CXM series CX750M 750W ATX12V v2.3; RAM: Crucial Ballistix Sport 4GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600

Comment: If you have another desktop computer available with a free SATA connection (or any other modern computer with a SATA-USB bridge), the only other suggestion I have would be to take your OS drive, connect it to your other computer as slave storage, manually copy your chipset drivers (may as well copy the rest while you're at it) over, then reconnect and try installing them on your new computer. It seems strange to me that Windows wouldn't at least load a generic USB controller driver, but I suppose it's not unheard of.

Comment: Have you got another USB drive available to see if that works?

Comment: Brian: Yeah, that was my thought as well. I have an extra SATA drive so I'm going to load the drivers on that.

Comment: Burgi: Three different USB drives, none detected :(

Comment: Do you have a BIOS with menu that prompts you on how you want to start your PC?

Comment: Yes, I can pick boot options from the BIOS. Forgive me for my ignorance, but what should I pick? I've tried booting from the bootable W7 usb key and repairing, but it just gets stuck - I left it running overnight and it still hangs at repair. I haven't tried the using my extra hard drive to transfer files yet, not  sure if I'll have time tonight, but will post if I get it to work.